# Is this method of accessing DB too wastey?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I have a relationship table for users and related users.

If I do `@user.related_users` I get a list of user_id that point to the users.

On my view I want to list their names with

```
<% current_user.related_users.each do |u| %>
<%= User.find(u).name %>
<% end %>
```

I worry that it might overload the DB too much, since it fetches every related_user from the DB every time someone access that view.

Is there a better way of doing this? or that is the way and there's nothing I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) is for. Ideally, in your model, `related_users` should be an association:

```
has_many :related_users # add conditions to find the related users if necessary
```

Then in your controller, fetch the `@user` like this:

```
@user = User.includes(:related_users)
```

That will perform only 1 query for all related users, instead of one query for each related user (a so-called  1+N problem).

Or, if you don't want to rewrite your model code, simply load all related users into a variable in your controller:

```
@related_user = User.where(id: current_user.related_users)
```

and iterate over that in your view. This will fetch all related users with a single query with a `WHERE id IN (...)` clause.